# How to create a circular crop mask for images in React Native

Tags: react-native, imagepicker

I've created a custom image picker using expo-media-library, and now I want to create a circular image crop mask, like on instagram or whatspp when you change the profile picture.

I found this package, https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker but it has some bugs.
Is it possible to create a custom image crop using existing react-native packages without working on native side?
Here's the packages I think could be useful:

1. @react-native-community/image-editor
2. react-native-masked-view/masked-view

Thank you